# SQL-TRIGGERS (BEFORE INSERT)

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert

I have a table "Employee" and a table "Manager" the relation between them is one to many,
each employee have one manager, each manager may have one or more employee.

I want there to be only one manager in the "Manager" table, therefore only one record.
I was thinking about creating a trigger BEFORE INSERT on "Manager" table and check if there exists a record, If no, then INSERT manager, if yes, then how do I cancel the INSERT or abort it?
Is there perhaps another way to do this?
I am still a bit new to MySQL and I am a bit confused.

Comment: It would be simpler not to grant insert access to the manager table after creating the one and only record there. But if you want a trigger, then see this question on the dba site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80969/can-i-permanently-lock-a-mysql-table-to-prevent-inserts

Comment: That worked, Thanks